# file not deleting form folder php

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to delete a file from uploads folders, but the code is not working.

It's deleting the row from the database, but not the file from the folder.

```
<?php
    extract($_REQUEST);
    include_once('include/dbcon.php');
    $dell= $_GET['del'];
    $sql1=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM notes WHERE notes_id='$dell'");
    $row1=mysqli_fetch_array($sql1);
    $delfile= $row1["file_path"];
    unlink("uploads/".$delfile);
    mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM notes WHERE notes_id='$dell'");
    header("location: deshboard.php");
?>
```

Comment: what is in `$row1["file_path"]`? is it only the final filename as it is named inside the uploads directory?

Comment: What's the full value of `"uploads/".$delfile`?  How have you confirmed the current working directory?  Does it work if you explicitly specify the full path to the file?

Comment: Assuming `unlink("uploads/".$delfile);` has a valid path to the file, it's probably the file permissions or the owner of the file.

Comment: SQL injection vulnerabilities here!

Comment: oh thank you very much sir actually it was saving as name is uploades/filename on file_path column now it was trying to delete uploads/uploads/filename with was not existing well thank you so much i have removed uploads/ from unlink("uploads/".$delfile); to unlink($delfile); now its working fine thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that the row in the database is the relative file path from within the uploads folder here. When using unlink [people sometimes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php#113854) use the [realpath](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) function to get the absolute pathname name.

Your code will look something like this:

```
unlink(realpath('uploads/' . $delfile));
```

Also, your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), please consider using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) when using variables within your queries

Answer (score 1):

The read and write permissions in the uploads folder might be the problem.

To check file permission you can use the following to check if the file is writable:

```
//Make sure to always get the full file path from $delfile
$delfile = /* path to the uploads folder */ . $row1["file_path"];
if (is_writable($delfile)) {
    print 'YES!!!: I am writeable';
} else {
    print 'NO!!!: File not writable, please fix me';
}
```

To check if the file is readable simply swap `is_writable()` with `is_readable()`

Learning how to use chmod helped me a lot when working with files/folders and its permissions.

[PHP documentation for chmod](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php)

Comment: @Muhammad Ali sanitize your SQL data

Answer (score 0):

First of all retrieve the full path of file :

```
$delfile = dirname(__FILE__) . $row1["file_path"];
```

Then make sure the file permissions is set to 0777:

```
chmod($delfile , 0777);
```

Final Result:

```
<?php
extract($_REQUEST);
include_once('include/dbcon.php');
$dell= $_GET['del'];
$sql1=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM notes WHERE notes_id='$dell'");
$row1=mysqli_fetch_array($sql1);
$delfile = dirname(__FILE__) . $row1["file_path"];


if (is_file($delfile )) {

   chmod($delfile , 0777);

   if (unlink($delfile )) {
      //'File deleted';
      mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM notes WHERE notes_id='$dell'");
      header("location: deshboard.php");
   } else {
      //'Cannot remove that file';
   }

} else {
  //'File does not exist';
}

?>
```

Comment: Curious, is it required to set the permissions to 0777 before deleting?

Comment: So even if a file is protected by no write rules, we should just overwrite those permissions and write anyways...? Unless this conforms to acceptance criteria, I think that this is dangerous and unnecessary.